# How to preserve new line character while performing psql copy command

Tags: postgresql, csv-import, postgresql-copy

I have following content in my csv file(with 3 columns):

```
141413,"\"'/x=/></script></title><x><x/","Mountain View, CA\"'/x=/></script></title><x><x/"

148443,"CLICK LINK BELOW TO ENTER^^^^^^^^^^^^^^","model\
\
xxx lipsum as it is\
\
100 sometimes unknown\
\
travel evening market\
"
```

When I import above mentioned csv in mysql using following command, it treats the backslash() as new line; which is the expected behavior.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '1.csv' INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

[MYSQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oMfm.png)

But when I try to import to psql using copy command, it treats \ as a normal character.

```
copy users from '1.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',', ENCODING 'utf8', NULL "\N", QUOTE E'\"', ESCAPE '\');
```

[postgres Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFEdp.png)

Comment: The `ESCAPE` option defines the character that escapes the quote character, it has nothing to do with multi-line records. Multi-line records are automatically detected if the value is quoted properly (in CSV mode). You need to remove the backslash from the input file (in general, the backlash has no meaning in SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing these `\` before importing the CSV file, e.g. using `perl -pe` or `sed` and the `STDIN` from [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html):

```
$ cat 1.csv | perl -pe 's/\\\n/\n/g' | psql testdb -c "COPY users FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',', ENCODING 'utf8', NULL "\N", QUOTE E'\"', ESCAPE '\');"
```

This is how it looks like after the import:

```
testdb=# select * from users;
   id   |                 company                 |                    location                     
--------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
 141413 | "'/x=/></script></title><x><x/          | Mountain View, CA"'/x=/></script></title><x><x/
 148443 | CLICK LINK BELOW TO ENTER^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ | model                                          +
        |                                         |                                                +
        |                                         | xxx lipsum as it is                            +
        |                                         |                                                +
        |                                         | 100 sometimes unknown                          +
        |                                         |                                                +
        |                                         | travel evening market                          +
        |                                         | 
(2 Zeilen)
```